# Map objects together in JS (es6)

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, mapping

I have two objects in JS:

```
positions: {
  top: { top: 10, left: 10 },
  bottom: { top: 10, left: 10 },
  left: { top: 10, left: 10 },
  right: { top: 10, left: 10 },
},

positionAdjustments: {
  top: { top: 0, left: 0 },
  bottom: { top: 5, left: 5 },
  left: { top: 0, left: 0 },
  right: { top: 0, left: 0 },
},
```

I want to combine them, so as to produce for example:-

```
positions: {
  top: { top: 10, left: 10 },
  bottom: { top: 15, left: 15 },
  left: { top: 10, left: 10 },
  right: { top: 10, left: 10 },
},
```

Is there a lodash method or some elegant way to achieve this without writing some recursive mapping function? Eg:

`positions.deepCombineValues(positionAdjustments);`

Comment: why last `left` is `0`?

Comment: probably a typo

Comment: @ozil sry was a typo!

Comment: @ManuelCheța thanks also!

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the keys and the wanted properties and adjust the positions.

```js
var object = { positions: { top: { top: 10, left: 10 }, bottom: { top: 10, left: 10 }, left: { top: 10, left: 10 }, right: { top: 10, left: 10 } }, positionAdjustments: { top: { top: 0, left: 0 }, bottom: { top: 5, left: 5 }, left: { top: 0, left: 0 }, right: { top: 0, left: 0 } } };

Object.keys(object.positions).forEach(function (k) {
    ['top', 'left'].forEach(function (l) {
        object.positions[k][l] += (object.positionAdjustments[k] || {})[l] || 0;
    });
})

console.log(object.positions);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 keys = Object.keys(positions)
 const result = keys.map(key => (
   {
     top: positions[key].top + positionsAdjustments[key].top,
     left: positions[key].left + positionsAdjustments[key].left,
   }
 ));
```

thats if you don't want to use `lodash` and only have `top` and `left` keys inside the `top` `left` `right` `bottom` objects. Can probaly improve this wayyy more

Comment: Thanks also! I was hoping lodash has a built in for this kind of thing ( adding keyed values in objects together ) but I don't think it does, guess it's too specific